# Current transformer wire issues

Tags: current, transformer, twisted-pair

I would greatly appreciate some advice regarding twisted pair conductors for a current transformer.

So, according to the manufacturer, whose equipment I am installing, I need to connect 10 AWG, shielded twisted pair cables to a CT (long distance between CT and measuring device).

My issue is that, this type of cable is not all that easy to find, and it seems like the lead times (when I can find it) are extremely long.

My question: Could I just make my own twisted pair cable out of individual 10 AWG cable, and run it in an insulated metal conduit and ground the conduit at one end?

I have already tested out a 3 meter piece of 12 AWG cable, twisted it with a drill, worked really well. Don't know how it will go doing a longer piece though.

Sounds ghetto, but could it work?

Comment: It seems to me that it would be more expensive to use conduit and 10 AWG conductors than the shielded cable. But as you said, if availability is the issue, use what you have. What is the total length needed? The manufacturer may have recommended 10 AWG for a specific length, and you may need to increase the gauge if going a greater distance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. the total length of the cable needs to be 15 meters. unfortunately, I will need to buy a entire roll at great expense. It actually works out much cheaper making my own twisted pair. I was just unsure if people actually did that kind of thing.

Comment: There's nothing magical about the stuff you can buy vs making your own.  It's mainly for convenience (time/effort to make vs buy).  As for grounding the conduit, since it's a long run, I'd make the ability to ground it at each end, and once in the middle.

Comment: If you want to measure only a current occasionally ... why don't use a classic very low cost 433 Tx or wifi transmitter?

Comment: I'd like to see the spec for a AWG10 CT STP wire.  I don't see why CAT 5 won't work with AWG20 routed at 90deg from power cables with shield gnded at source only.  I suppose AWG10 is greater separation and lower than 100 pF/m

Comment: Is CT impedance specified?  I'd be inclined to use 75 ohm CATV Coax if the burden is ~ 100 ohms

Comment: But this depends on secondary current limit